# Laravel - Managing Time for a riddle site

Tags: php, web-applications, web, laravel

I am using laravel to build a riddle web application where user can post the riddle and set a end time (eg: 10hrs/2days from the date of post). Other members can answer the riddle within the given time. best answer within time wins. I want that the riddle will not show up in page if the time has ended.
I need guidance on how can I approach only the section where riddle is not available after the time limit. Will checking current time with posted time can help? or there is other easier way.
I am new to laravel.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is far too broad im afraid. Its about the entire design of the app (language and framework dont even come into it yet).

Comment: I am really sorry. I just want to know will checking current time with posted time can help?? or there is other easier way??

Comment: As per the answer, you would store the end date somewhere (probably sql database) and when a riddle is requested, check that the date hasnt been passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store are riddles in the database. You insert them and you give them a startdate, wich can be your current time... and an end date. This value is something you can set in the back-end.

When a user wants to visit a page, you do a time time check for example: (Dummy data)
The user navigates to:

```
www.riddles.com/112
```

You check if the id 112 exists. ( FindOrFail ).

Yes, it exists?

> Do a check in your database for the endtime. If this end-time is not yet reached you show the page. Else you redirect to some other page.

Your question wasn't 100% clear to me but I guess that is something you would like to start doing? If not, please give a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am sorry if this question was child-like. This will help me a lot. can I check it with a internet time because user can change their computer time. And do laravel has classes/functions for doing time based work.

Comment: @BryanS you use your servers time, not the users, so you can trust it